# Compare memory locations of two primitives

Tags: java, variables, compare, primitive

Is there any way which I can compare memory locations of two `int`s in java?

```
int x = 25;
int y = 25;
```

I want to check and prove whether the both variables are referring the same value or they are created twice.

```
x == y
```

above line compares the literal *values* that's not what I want. Any idea?

Comment: There is an `Integer` pool in Java, but I don't think this exists for primitives.

Comment: No. That is not possible in Java.

Comment: If I remember correctly, two primitives cannot share the same memory location. Finals _might_, but I’m doubtful.

Comment: Your question shows that probably you are on the wrong way. Could you please explain why do you want to do this?

Comment: @AlexR No important reason. Just to explore how the language works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this won’t be possible to do with code, you can look at the bytecode generated by your snippet.

```
0: bipush        25
2: istore_1
3: bipush        25
5: istore_2
6: return
```

Seeing that `bipush` is called twice, it would appear that two stack allocations are made. An optimization could very well be made later on, though.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Once you’ve compiled your code, use `javap -verbose ClassName.class`, replacing `ClassName` with your file’s name.

Comment: I agree that looking at byte code is a good idea, but as said: we have no idea what the JIT will turn this into. If semantically possible, it would most likely optimize out such reusages of values.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, that would make sense. I haven’t been able to find any information on that yet.

Comment: Nice idea though. Thanks!!

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala No problem!

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for is not possible.

Primitive values in Java are just that: primitive *values*. Nothing in their "definition" relates to memory locations.

The javac compiler will do constant folding though, and of course the jit will apply all kinds of optimization at runtime if that is your question. But there is no way for you to get to the "memory layout" regarding primitive values. Even the *com.misc.Unsafe" and VarHandle stuff solely deals with reference types.